# c# extract a method with lambda parameter for linq query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I have tons of this type of conditional query params with hibernate. This begs for some kind of encapsulation but I'm new to linq queries and not sure if it is at all possible. Kind of exchange this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(params.test))
{
    vq = vq.WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.test).IsIn(params.test.StartsWith(";") ? params.test.Substring(1).Split(';') : params.test.Split(';'));
}
```

for this:

```
vq = newShinyFunction(vq, params.test, (c => c.test));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any lambda expression like (c => c.test) will naturally cast to a delegate or expression matching it's type.  In this case `Func<typeofc, typeoftest>` or `Expression<Func<typeofc, typeoftest>>`, or `Func<Object, Object>` for that matter.

Check your api reference for WhereRestrictionOn to see what type it takes in. Use that as the type for your final parameter of your new shiny function.

Comment: Thanks, `Expression<Func<typeofc, object>>` was a catch. Much cleaner now.